# Listening to Multiple Shiurim at the Same Time

Tags: torah-study

Most computers offer a feature where you can have several tabs open at the same time and play different audio at the same time as well. If one listens to different shiurim on each tab, let’s say about 5, will he receive 5 times the reward of Torah Mitzvot, considering each letter of Torah is a mitzvah? If so, can the same thing be applied to a real life scenario, by multiple speakers giving a shiur Torah at the same exact time? Please cite sources. Thanks!

Comment: This would have been a great question for [Purim Torah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/purim-torah-in-jest) season.

Comment: Maybe helpful to buy 2 computers

Answer (score 5):

If listening to 5 shiurim at once, he will not only not get 5 times the schar, but he will get zero schar, since he cannot follow/understand any of the shiurim. (Kal Vachomer from [תרי קלי לא משתמעי](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%99+%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%99+%D7%9C%D7%90+%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%AA%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%99))

Comment: @רבות https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89043/tzitzis-a-mitzvah-per-pair