# Listening to an Online Shiur While watching Tv

Tags: torah-study

Let’s say one listens to an online shiur Torah while watching TV or talking to a friend on the phone. Would sources still consider this learning Torah, as I believe he subconsciously hears the shiur? If not, do sources consider this bitul Torah?

Comment: Could’ve sworn we’ve had this question already but I can’t find it right now

Comment: @DonielF I think the dupe is listening to a shiur while simumtanously doing something else on the computer.

Comment: @JoshK I may have been thinking of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/98999/, also asked by the OP

Comment: It's essentially a dupe thereof, @Doniel, I agree

Comment: @DonielF You're thinking of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/99195/759 To quote a comment there: "How is this learning? It is not"